# Random Index Generator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, random

Okay so I am trying to make a program to help my stay on top of my Visual Basic Skill until next semester.

So I decided to create a Random Cell Phone Number generator and I have come up with an Issue Whenever I select "Bethany" as my city it only pulls "342" no matter how many times I run it, instead of a random index. Below is my code maybe you can help me.

```
'======================================================

'Adam W. Schneider

'Random Cellphone number Generator

'VB 1 Refresh

'======================================================



Public Class vbform1

    'Clears the list box.

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        'Clear the list Boxes

        lstPhoneNumbers.Items.Clear()
        lstBoxCity.Items.Clear()

    End Sub

    'Closes the Form.

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click

        'Determines the area code selected

        If lstAreaCodes.SelectedItem.ToString = "513" Then

            'Clears the box of previous results before displaying new results

            lstBoxCity.Items.Clear()

            'Writes the cities available for area code 513

            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cincinnati")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Middletown")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Lebanon (Warren)")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("South Lebanon")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Mason")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Little Miami")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Oxford")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bethel")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Harrison")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Clermont")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bethany")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Butlerville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fayetteville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Felicity")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Monroe")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Morning Sun")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Morrow")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Newtonsville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Reily")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Seven Mile")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Shandon")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Trenton")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Waynesville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Williamsburg")

            'Determines the area code selected

        ElseIf lstAreaCodes.SelectedItem.ToString = "937" Then

            'Clears the box of previous results before displaying new results

            lstBoxCity.Items.Clear()

            'Writes the cities available for area code 937

            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Aberdeen")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Anna")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Ansonia")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Arcanum")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Beavercreek")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Belfast")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bellbrook")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Belle Center")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bellefontaine")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Blanchester")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Botkins")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bowersville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bradford")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Brookville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Byhalia")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Camden")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Catawba")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cedarville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Centerville (Mongomery)")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Christiansburg")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Clarksville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Covington")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Danville (Highland)")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Dayton")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("De Graff")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Decatur")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Donnelsville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("East Liberty")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Eaton")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Eldorado")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Englewood")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Enon")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fairborn")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Famersville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fletcher-Lena")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fort Loramie")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Franklin")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Georgetown")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Germantown")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Gettysburg")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Gratis")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Greenfield")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Greenville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Hamersville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Higginsport")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Hillsboro")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Hollansburg")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Huntsville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Jackson Center")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Jamestown")

            'Determines the area code selected

        ElseIf lstAreaCodes.SelectedItem.ToString = "859" Then

            'Clears the box of previous results before displaying new results

            lstBoxCity.Items.Clear()

            'Writes the cities available for area code 859

            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Alexandria")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Berea")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Boone")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bryantsville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Burgin")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Butler")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Carlisle")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cornishville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Convington")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cythiana")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Danville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Falmouth")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Ford")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Glencole")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Harrodsburg")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Independence")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Junction City")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Kirksville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Lancaster")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Lexington")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Little Rock")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Mackville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Midway")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Millersburg")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Mooresville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("North Middletown")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Paint Lick")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Paris")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Perryville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Richmond")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Salvisa")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Springfield")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Versailles")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Waco")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Walton")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Warsaw")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Williamstown")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Willisburg")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Wilmore")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Winchester")

            'Determines the area code selected

        ElseIf lstAreaCodes.SelectedItem.ToString = "812" Then

            'Clears the box of previous results before displaying new results

            lstBoxCity.Items.Clear()

            'Writes the cities available for area code 812

            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Alfordsville-Glendale")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Aurora")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Austin")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Brandon")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Batesville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bedford")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bicknell")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Birdseye")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bloomfield")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Boonville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Brazil")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Brownstown")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bruceville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Butlerville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Campbellsburg")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Canaan")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Center Point")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Central")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Chandler")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Charlestown")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Chrisney")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Clay City")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Clearspring")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Columbus")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cory")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Corydon")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Crandall")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Crane")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cross Plains")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Crothersville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cynthiana")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Dale")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Decker")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Dillsboro")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Dubois")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Dugger")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("East Enterprise")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Edinburgh")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Elberfeld")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Elizabeth")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Elizabethtown")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Elletsville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Elnora")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("English")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Evansville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fairbanks")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Farmersburg")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Ferdinand")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Flat Rock")

            'Determines the area code selected

        ElseIf lstAreaCodes.SelectedItem.ToString = "765" Then

            'Clears the box of previous results before displaying new results

            lstBoxCity.Items.Clear()

            'Writes the cities available for area code 765

            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Albany")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Alexandria")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Amboy")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Anderson")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Arlington")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Atlanta")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Attica")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Battle Ground")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bloomingdale")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bloutsville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Buck Creek")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Bunker Hill")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Burlington")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cambridge City")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Carthage")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cayuga")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Centerville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Chesterfield")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Clarks Hill")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Clinton")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cloverdale")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Coatesville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Colfax")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Connersville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Covington")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Crawfordsville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Cutler")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Dana")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Darlington")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Delphi")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Denver")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Dunkirk")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Eaton")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Elwood")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Eminence")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fairmount")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Farmland")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fillmore")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fountain City")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Fowler")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Frankfort")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Frankton")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Gaston")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Geetingsville")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Glenwood")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Greencastle")
            lstBoxCity.Items.Add("Greens Fork")

        End If




    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Calculate Random Prefix based upon selected city

        If lstBoxCity.SelectedItem.ToString = "Bethany" Then

            Dim Bethany As String() = {"298", "342", "443", "644", "712", "755", "759", "777", "779", "847"}
            Dim randomBethany As String = Bethany(CInt(Rnd(Bethany.Count)))

            MsgBox(randomBethany.ToString)

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In the future, you'll get better responses if you can produce a more concise example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Randomize()` before picking the random number; otherwise you will wind up with the same random number each time, because the seed is the same, like this:

```
' Initialize the random-number generator.
Randomize()

Dim Bethany As String() = {"298", "342", "443", "644", "712", "755", "759", "777", "779", "847"}

' Generate random value between 1 and then length of your Bethany array
Dim randomBethany As String = Bethany(Int((Bethany.Count * Rnd()) + 1))
```

---

Read [Rnd Function (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This Answers my question and does exactly what I want it to do, Now just to get it to do it 10 times with a Do While loop and write to a List Box. Wish me luck I'll be back with issues.

Comment: @user3119737 - glad this helped you, if you feel it answered your question then please accept the answer and/or up-vote the answer. :-) It is recommended that you do not piggyback off of questions with "just one more question" type updates to your question. Open up a new question with your new code and new problem.

Comment: To accept an answer look for a checkmark next to the answer, it will turn green when you click it. The up arrow above the checkmark is what you click to up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

The `Rnd` method always returns a number between 0 and 1.  If you want a higher number, you'd need to multiply it by something.  However, you really should, instead, be using the `Random` class to generate your random numbers.  The `Rnd` method is an old VB6-style method which is provided primarily for backwards compatibility.  The `Random` class does have a much easier syntax too, where you can specify the range of numbers in which you want the result to fall.

```
Dim r As New Random()
Dim randomBethany As String = Bethany(r.Next(0, Bethany.Count - 1))
```

However, you should create the `Random` object once, when your form loads, since it re-seeds the random number generation algorithm each time you create a new one.

Comment: This was great at generating a Random Index but not the information within The Random Index. While I agree with you that I shouldn't use Rnd but Karl Anderson work's for my particular situation.

Comment: Sorry.  I was just trying to keep the example as simple as possible.  I updated my answer to show how to get the string from the array at that random index.  It's actually even simpler with the `Random` class because it actually returns an `Integer`, so you don't need to call `CInt`.